Tone.js if play many notes will not match the Loop (metronome)
I try to enter my sheet music into Tone.js, but the tempo sounds not correct if I enable metronome as the same time.
And I realize it depends on how many notes of my music, if it's few notes then works fine.
In actual case I have nix 4n, 8n., t16, ...etc., complicate subdivisions.
To simplify the issue, I create a test script with only 8n and still can replicate the issue, which means it's not because I'm calculate subdivisions wrong.
Here is my test script https://jsfiddle.net/cbwt2q8m/
I copy the official website and did very little changes.
function metronome() {
  // create two monophonic synths
  const synthA = new Tone.Synth().toDestination();
  const synthB = new Tone.Synth().toDestination();
  //play a note every quarter-note
  const loopA = new Tone.Loop((time) => {
    synthA.triggerAttackRelease("C5b", "8n", time);
  }, "1m").start(0);
  //play another note every off quarter-note, by starting it "8n"
  const loopB = new Tone.Loop((time) => {
    synthB.triggerAttackRelease("C4b", "8n", time);
  }, "4n").start(0);
  // all loops start when the Transport is started
  Tone.getTransport().start();
}

Then create a test script to play other sounds together.
function play() {
  const synth = new Tone.Synth().toDestination();
  const now = Tone.now();
  Array(4)
    .fill(['C3', 'D3', 'E3', 'F3', 'G3', 'A3', 'B3', 'C4'])
    .flat()
    .forEach((note, i) => {
      const subdivision = '8n'
      const duration = Tone.Time(subdivision).toSeconds() * i + now
      synth.triggerAttackRelease(note, "8n", duration);
    })
}

Then play them together.
document.querySelector('#play').addEventListener('click', () => {
  play()
  metronome()
})

In this example with 4 * 8 = 32 notes is works well, all sounds matched with the tempo.
But if I change the Array(4) to Array(40) which is 320 notes, then the tempo will not matched?
Which part I using the Tone.js in the wrong way?

I solved by using Time and Part.
https://jsfiddle.net/9xu2fhqe/
function play() {
  const synth = new Tone.Synth().toDestination();
  const {
    xs
  } = Array(40)
    .fill(['C3', 'D3', 'E3', 'F3', 'G3', 'A3', 'B3', 'C4'])
    .flat()
    .reduce(({
      xs,
      t
    }, note) => {
      const subdivision = '8n'
      const x = {
        time: t,
        note,
        subdivision
      }
      return {
        xs: xs.concat(x),
        t: t + Tone.Time(subdivision),
      }
    }, {
      xs: [],
      t: Tone.Time('0')
    })
  new Tone.Part((time, x) => {
    synth.triggerAttackRelease(x.note, x.subdivision, time);
  }, xs).start(0)
}

First, be sure to calculate time directly with the Time object if calculating with numbers might have decimal precision problems.
Second, be sure to use Part, Sequence, ... etc. to manage the sound to start/stop.
This way, we can control the transport together.
refers:

https://www.guitarland.com/MusicTheoryWithToneJS/PlayRhythms.html
https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js/wiki/Time

